# cannot reference grouped data in summarize(across(...))

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, tidyverse

When I try to create several columns within `summarize()`, I can reference a newly created column name in the same summarize statement.

Example:

Goal: Try to calculate the standard error ("se") based on the standard deviation ("sd").

#### Step 1 (start to assign sd for se):

```
data %>% 
  group_by(style) %>% 
  summarise(across(score,list(mean = mean, sd = sd, se = sd)))
```

returns

```
  style score_mean score_sd score_se
* <fct>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 S1           3.5    0.707    0.707
```

#### Step 2: calculate se based on sd

```
data %>% 
  group_by(style) %>% 
  summarise(across(score,list(mean = mean, sd = sd, se = sd/sqrt(nrow(score)))))
```

returns

```
Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `..1`.
x non-numeric argument to binary operator
ℹ Input `..1` is `across(score, list(mean = mean, sd = sd, se = sd/sqrt(nrow(data))))`.
ℹ The error occured in group 1: style = "S1".
```

#### Step 3 debugging assignment term

#### 3a) grouped data reference

I replaced the grouped data in `nrow(score))` by the other column names or even `nrow(data)`, but they all led to the same error message.

#### 3b) assignment operation

I replaced the assignement for se `sd/sqrt(nrow(score)))` with different variations leading all to the same error. The simplest was `sd/2`, so even dividing by a constant doesn't work.

#### 3c) assignment reference

I replaced `sd` by `score_sd` to reference the new column created, as seen in the output (Step 1). Still the same error message.

#### Question: Why does Step 1 work but not Step 2?

The error message just refers to the whole `across()` statement, so doesn't help to narrow down the root cause.

My hunch is that I have to reference the grouped data somehow, but I tried 
`se = sd(.)/sqrt(nrow(data)` with no success.

Would be grateful for any hints...

Minimal reproducible example:

```
data <- structure(list(style = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5"), class = "factor"), 
    param = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), score = c(4, 
    1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many trial & error attempts, I found the solution myself. This is for everyone who is not yet familiar with the `across` function, as `dplyr 1.0.0` is not yet released.

So the answer to my question is:

1. You must reference the grouped data by the `.` operator - BUT ONLY IF you use the `purrr` formula operator `~`!
2. However, you must *NOT* reference the grouped data in the `n()` function, as the `n()` does NOT accept the `.` operator.

The second point took endless trials to find out, and is the reason why I wanted to share this solution.

You might not find it intuitive to understand either that, even though `n()` is defined with brackets, it is never allowed to use the `.` operator as it always refers to the grouped data.

This is how this double trick looks like:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(style) %>% 
  summarise(across(
    score, 
    list(mean = mean, sd = sd, se = ~sd(.)/sqrt(n()))
  ))
```

If you know it, it's easy :-)